# Calculate the confidence score for the machine learning results

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, xgboost, confidence-interval

I have applied Xgboost classifier to classify my output. I already included the probability by using  predict_proba. However, I would like to add a confidence interval score to show how confident the model is or

```
import xgboost as xgb
xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(base_score=0.2, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
              colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=1, enable_categorical=False,
              gamma=0, gpu_id=-1, importance_type=None,
              interaction_constraints='', learning_rate=0.300000012,
              max_delta_step=0, max_depth=40, min_child_weight=1, 
              monotone_constraints='()', n_estimators=100, n_jobs=10,
              num_parallel_tree=1, objective='multi:softprob', predictor='auto',
              random_state=0, reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=None,
              subsample=1, tree_method='exact', validate_parameters=1,
              verbosity=None)
xgb_model.fit(X_train_vectors_tfidf, y_train)



y_predict = xgb_model.predict(X_test_vectors_tfidf)
y_prob = xgb_model.predict_proba(X_test_vectors_tfidf)[:,1]
print(classification_report(y_test,y_predict))
print('Confusion Matrix:',confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predict))
```

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.